# Array format Conversion in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have got an array which looks like the following:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 4 ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 0 ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 5 ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) )
```

and I would like to convert it into the following format:

```
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,2,0,0,5,1]
```

How can I achieve this conversion using php?

All the help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to access the array with this or do you want the output to be this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way: (assuming that you want it to actually output the string `[5,6,...,2]`

```
<?php
 $ids=array();
foreach($yourArray as $k=>$v){
    $ids[] = $v['id'];
}
$resultCsv = implode(',', $ids);
$result = '['.$resultCsv.']';
echo $result
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php):

```
$result = array_column($array, 'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` or `array_walk`:

With `array_map`:

```
$new = array_map(function ($value) { return $value['id']; }, $theArray);
print_r($new);
```

With `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($theArray, function (&$value, $key) { $value = $value['id']; };
print_r($theArray);
```

The main differences between these is that `array_map` produces a completely new array, and you dont get the key passed to the callback function. `array_walk` on the other hand works on the array by reference and the callback also gets the key.

Now its unclear to me whether you wanted the array restructured (as i provided solutions for) or if you want it in a specific string format like the `[0,1,2,3,...]` you provided. If you did want it in a string format all you need to do now is call `json_encode` on it:

```
// note if you used array_map pass the variable that holds the result of the call
// (in my example that would be $new); If you used array_walk then pass the same array
// you supplied as the argument to the call (in my exmaple that would be $theArray)

$arrString = json_encode($theArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can process every member of the array and append every currently processed sub-array's member "id" to a new array:

```
<?php
    // code
    foreach $array as $member {
        $newarray[]=$member["id"];
    }
    // code
?>
```